# eclipse debugging keys not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm debugging my C++ project with eclipse Indigo cdt- and for some reason that F* keys stopped working when i'm debugging . ( F8, F6, etc... that allow me to move to next line, etc. )

Anyone have any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is late and already answered but I ran into the same issue debugging an android project.  The accepted answer did not fix my problem even after many IDE restarts.  My fix was to go into the Preferences and under General -> Keys.  Then order list by key and look for F5-F8 "Debug Step Into, Over, Return and Run".  I highlighted each one and clicked "Restore Command", then restarted Eclipse... this seemed to work for me.

Comment: Yeah Latest version is doing weirder things like CTRL-S won't work or delete key but only happens once in a while.  Restarting Eclipse usually fixes it though.

Comment: Okay - got it working by resetting the perspective AND clicking the checkbox for undoing customizations.  I always re-arrange the default view appear by moving panels, getting rid of the outline, etc.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Work for me for eclipse photon. Thanks!

Comment: lol dude did you see my answer that was 7 years ago!  Probably yeah this works now and they fixed this bug in the IDE.

Answer (score 16):

I have no idea how I made the keys disappear in the first place, but what fixed it was to reset the debug perspective (You can do this from Window->Reset Perspective or right clicking on the Debug Perspective button from the top right panel and then choosing reset).

Afterward restart eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked but I had to click the checkbox to overwrite any customizations.   Then I re-customized, saved the perspective and back in business!

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same exact issue.  It turned out it was the F Lock key on my Microsoft keyboard.  If you have a Microsoft keyboard with an F Lock key, I suggest pressing it to toggle the state and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks! If only I had that advice 4 years ago when I encountered the problem! Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this happens but I've found that changing focus from one view to another (debug, or the editor) will usually fix it.

Comment: not in my case :) its consistent, even after restarts of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to bypass the Eclipse feature to make the keys mode sensitive. You'll lose the ability to use the keys in some non-debug contexts, but at least they'll work for debugging.

1. Open the **Keys** preferences section (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice).
2. Click the **Binding** column header to set the sort order, and find the debugging keys (<kbd>F5</kbd>,<kbd>F6</kbd>,<kbd>F7</kbd>...).
3. For each key, change the **When** action value from **Debugging** to **In Window**. Alternatively, you may find there is something more specific than "In Window" that works for your environment.

Comment: That worked for me too, but... This binding change to "In Windows" may have a drawback -- some bindings might be conflicting in the "In Window" state. For example, F5 + "In Windows" collides with bunch of refreshes.

Comment: @ZamanRohoman suggested the following (I haven't tested): At the bottom of the window under “Show key binding when command is invoked”, check the 2 boxes “Through keyboard” and “Through mouse click”.

Answer (score 0):

Well going to Windows -> Preferences -> Select **Keys** under **General** -> Restore defaults -> restart eclipse worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Luna 4.4.2  Mac OS X 10.10.5

When I start Debug, Eclipse tries to make a network connection.  If I allow, sometimes the step toolbuttons are disabled.  If I deny, they are enabled.  The dialog to deny or allow comes from the OS.  I run Eclipse as a standard user, so I am prompted for a privileged user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified it on **Eclipse juno** and F6, F8 is working properly. Just follow following steps.

1 Click on Window Tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEKBQ.jpg

2 Select Customize Perspective https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUkU.jpg

3 In Tool Bar Visibility make sure Debug is checked https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iC7N.jpg

4 Select Shortcuts tab and click on Java and make sure Java Run/Debug is checked. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5NrF.jpg

Hope this will help you out. Happy Coding