# Eclipse - Run/Debug shortcut key doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse I can only run/debug my project by using one of the menu buttons. Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> does nothing. I've mapped Debug Last Launched to all kinds of various keyboard shortcuts to see if another program running in the background was intercepting the key presses and that doesn't seem to be the case. Every other keyboard shortcut seems to work fine such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

Any help? The shortcut key works on my other computer and I keep instinctively trying to press it and it's drastically slowing down my work efficiency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse debugging keys not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804886/eclipse-debugging-keys-not-working)

Comment: **if you have a Microsoft 4000 keyboard** --> check to see if the `F Lock` is enabled or not --> if the `F lock` is not enabled the `F11` key will actually be mapped to a different keyboard event... you need to enable `F lock` and try again.

Answer (score 44):

The only solution works for me ;

Open Key mappings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice)
Find the debugging shorcuts (<kbd>F5</kbd>,<kbd>F6</kbd>,<kbd>F7</kbd>...) and select

then change the **When** action value from "**Debugging**" to "**In Window**"

Comment: I had the same issue with the `Run to Line` (Ctrl+R) shortcut and change the when statement from `Debugging` to `Debugging Java`. Thank you :)

Comment: Works for me too. I hate eclipse for bugs like that and for it's 101 perspectives, views, contexts etc.

Comment: "In Window" might be a bit too generic, and for F5, it conflicts with the various refresh options.

Answer (score 12):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
For each key that doesn't work: Set your binding to whatever you want. - I just copy the command then **change "When" from "Debugging" to "Editing Java Source"**.
good luck.

Answer (score 6):

I battled with a new Dell laptop, so in case it saves someone time ....

By default, the F-key priority was set for sound, brightness and music, e.g.  <kbd>F9</kbd> brings up Windows search.
  --> This is without pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and the desired Fkey as expected.

To toggle the priority, look for <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
 That allows <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> etc to work as expected.
 You can press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> for skipping music tracks

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has a fn lock/toggle that switches between fn and the f1-f12 keys, make sure that you didn't toggle the other mode by accident.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **default key mappings**, restoring defaults might work.

`Window` | `Preferences` | `General` | `Keys` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>), then hit `Restore Defaults` and `OK`.

For **custom mappings**, I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414891/1845976).

Comment: That's correct. I changed the answer to reflect this info

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>F11</kbd>.
It worked for me. Im using Eclipse in ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if another program is trying to hook keyboard messages. Maybe that program prevents the Eclipse to receive some keystrokes including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.
I had this problem and finally I found out that the problem is about my dictionary application which used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to popup. After disabling the hotkey in the dictionary application, Eclipse started to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> correctly!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: My post doesn't directly react the original malfunctioning-F11-behavoir question. But the issue I had seems quite similar and definitely it relates to some other (quite highly voted) answers.

---

I've bumped into a similar issue too when I upgraded to Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen and needed to install several plugins from a scratch. F* keys didn't work in the debug perspective even though the appropriate key bindings were configured correctly.

Unfortunately, neither reseting perspective nor reseting key bindings (as suggested in some comments here) helped.

The trick that fixed that for me was:

> Preferences > Run/Debug > Perspectives > Restore Defaults

That revived the F* keys functionality in my debug perspective. I don't thing this is the universal way how to bring the behaviour back, but among the other "Resets to defaults" this one may be the right one in some cases, so it's worth trying.