# function only F8 doesn't work during debug into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, editor

During debug into eclipse
Other function key like <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> & <kbd>F7</kbd> works perfectly
but only the <kbd>F8</kbd> function doesn't work
What will be the reason ? This problem spending my more time when debug mode
Would you please share your idea about it?

Comment: sometimes you need to push f8 and f7 twice to make it work. if that's not it, it must be a system problem, say for example your keyboard has a sepcial function key on f8 (like mine to switch to an external monitor)

Comment: @kw4nta not at mine.. outside of debug key F8 perfectly works... frankly say F8 key works before some day perfectly... but now it stopped in debug mode..

Comment: I had the same problem. I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804886/eclipse-debugging-keys-not-working/14937559#14937559?newreg=004c0cece23741678a94c6d581c9f22d

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Eclipse key bindings? Could it have been changed by any chance?

To check, go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys > search for "Resume".

You could also try to bind "Resume" to some other key and see if that works for you.