# Unable to debug using eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

So there is a small java program to add two numbers.

There is one break-point.

I used `Debug as -> Java Application`.

But still, `Step Into`, `Step Over`, `Resume`, `Suspend` and `Terminate` buttons are disabled in my eclipse.

See below:

[image]

Debugger recognized the breakpoint at `int b = 3` but still the buttons are disabled.

Everything was working fine yesterday.

What should be the cause?

Comment: Why dont you use 'f6' for step line by line and 'f7' and 'f8' step by debug point. give it a try

Comment: nothing happens as if debugger is off.

Comment: You did click on the correct method frame icon?

Comment: yes, I right clicked inside the opened class `Test.java` and then `Debug As -> Java Application`.

Comment: Also try left-clicking on the line `Test.main(String[]) line: 7` in Debug window (the one with blue lines icon on the left) - sometimes the IDE loses track of what process and stack frame you're trying to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibles solutions and cause [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804886/eclipse-debugging-keys-not-working).

The commands got disabled, probably from previous customization, (check General -> Keys) but I wouldn't think this can be the only reason to be cause of this issue.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks.. Your link that explains the causes had the solution. Going to the `Window->Reset Debug Perspective` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue and fixed it. The following are the possible solutions:

1. Make sure that your skip all break point option is disabled
2. Reset your debug perspective in perspective options.
3. Make sure to restart eclipse after doing above things